# Long Execution Time with pdfLaTeX on Mac OS X

Tags: graphics, pdftex, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast PNG embedding using pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39929/fast-png-embedding-using-pdflatex)

I'm using pdfLaTeX on Mac OS X v10.7.3, and I've added about 25 PNG images to a LaTeX document that is roughly 35 pages long. The images are between 90 and 175 KB each. Now that I've added the images, pdfLaTeX takes over 5 minutes to run:

```
real    5m52.787s
user    0m9.438s
sys     0m0.340s
```

Is there any way to speed up the compilation, like re-using the image resources, or is this just how long pdfLaTeX takes with images? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Please have a look at the log file: is the inclusion of the images marked with "PNG copy"? See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39929/fast-png-embedding-using-pdflatex/39933#39933 and try to measure the speed with the `draft` option given to the documentclass (`\documentclass[draft]{...}`)