# image cache for pdflatex like for dvipdfmx?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, dvipdfmx

When using `dvipdfmx` for PDF generation from DVI, one has the `-I` option, which caches images for a specified number of hours between runs. This is *very* useful to speed PDF generation when including large image files. As far as I can tell, there is no such option for `pdftex/pdflatex` when generating PDF. Such a question was asked before ([Caching includegraphics{} image files for speed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178572/caching-includegraphics-image-files-for-speed)), but was not answered definitively either way and may have been interpreted for PNG files only. Is it possible, at least for inclusion of PDF files? I know about draft mode; that does not answer my question because it does not include the images.

Comment: The `-I` option in dvipdfmx is for `eps` files. `eps` files are
changed into `pdf` files before inclusion. The `-I` option caches
transformed `pdf` files in order to skip the changing process
which is time-consuming. For other format of images like `pdf`,
`png`, ..., `-I` option does nothing.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you could copy all the images to the RAM file system (`tmpfs`) which is usually mounted on `/dev/shm` and add this directory to the search path with `\graphicspath{{/dev/shm/}}`. Not sure whether it makes a difference, though.

Comment: @AlexG I am on Linux, and I tried using ```/dev/shm```, but it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion, anyway.

Comment: Did you look into the log file and verify the location from which the images were loaded? (Just an idea.)

Comment: Maybe the difference is negligible nowadays, as SSD discs are mostly in use. Did you experience a noticeable speed-up with `dvipdfmx -I`?

Comment: @AlexG I had to change the actual ```include``` line to give the path, and I did check the log file. I do use SSD. When I use ```dvipdfmx -I``` on a different file that uses a very large number of EPS figures, the difference is clear. I did not test changing this PDF figure to EPS.